# How to update internal object fields to a MongoDB using GORM?

Tags: mongodb, grails

Fields of the object in the database are not updated and there are no errors.

```
class Transaction {
    static mapWith = "mongo"
    ObjectId id
    String name
    Address address
    static embedded = ['address']
}
class Address {
    String country
}

def tempMethod() {
    def transaction = Transaction.first()
    transaction.address = new Address(country: "Canada")
    transaction.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
}
```

Comment: Is `tempMethod` supposed to be what you're attempting? What isn't working?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
'tempoMethod' is method in the controller to verify the preservation of the internal object Address in Transaction object using GORM ( .save() ) in the MongoDB database.
After the method is executed, the Address object is not updated in the database.
Is it my fault in the system or does Gorm not update the internal objects of the MongDB?

Comment: @James Kleeh  Class Transaction is Domain, class Adress is groovy class

Comment: i'm experiencing kind of a similar problem right now with plugin version 6.0.12.RELEASE can you tell me which one are you using?